# Loop doesn't work, nasm

Tags: linux, loops, assembly, nasm

I made a program to output counts from 1-9, but after compiling I only get a "0". I have no idea, where I made a mistake. I would like to ask for help. Below I place a code:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
        xor esi,esi
        mov esi,[variable]

_middle:
        mov [variable],esi

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,variable
        mov edx,[length]
        int 80h

        inc esi

        cmp esi,57
        jbe _middle

_end:
        mov eax,1
        int 80h

section .data

variable        db      48
length  dd      $-variable
```

Comment: If you get only one character output then obviously `esi` is greater than 57 when you test. What's `variable` supposed to hold? You declare it as two bytes but you read/write a dword value to it.

Comment: That's fact, I overwrited 0 to that. There are possibility to declare a variable without writing to that? I deleted "add esi, 48" but now program do nothing.

Comment: what debugger are you using? this should be easy to debug if you step through the entire code

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. Tomorrow I'll try to check. We work on university server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `esi` but you forget to store it into `variable`, so at the top of the loop the original value is read again. Move the line that stores `esi` *after* the label `_middle`. (And you don't need the line to retrieve `variable` into `esi` anymore.)

As it seems you are working with ASCII values, you should not start `variable` with the value `0` but with `48`:

```
_start:
        mov esi, 48
_middle:
        mov esi,[variable]
```

Alternatively, start with `variable` initialized:

```
variable        db      '0'
```

but that requires some more rewriting.

Comment: Ok, I have understood how to AscII works :). But I still don't understand overtwriting into esi. In the first line in middle I have "mov [variable],esi", so it should work. Later the value of esi is increment, and after it we overwrite "esi+1" into variable. Isn't it? Yet we still increase value of variable in my opinion. Look, that I project variable, not esi :).

Comment: You moved the *value* in `variable` into `esi`, but that doesn't automatically link them together. Perhaps you are thinking of the *address*: `mov variable, esi; inc [esi]` -- the other way around? That can also work.

Comment: Hmm... let me think. What is the difference between "inc esi" or "inc [esi]"? I thought that register works only as a temporary variable, which only store a value.

Comment: So? `esi` still does that -- an address is also just a number that can be stored in to a register. The **crucial** difference is what these two instructions do (which may be a good reason to find yourself an Intel Assembler manual). `inc esi` increases the number in `esi`, whereas `inc [esi]` increases the value *at the address* `esi` (and it thus needs a qualifier for the size of that value).